# aws s3 sync does it copy the file when is file descriptor is still open

Tags: amazon-s3, synchronization

i am trying to sync my sftp server with s3 and i have a question regarding it.
aws s3 sync . s3://test/

I have sync process running as a cron every 10 mins. Suppose i have a large file that is being transferred to my sftp account does s3 sync copy the file to s3 without the file being closed and completely transfered or does it transfer files only that are closed.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?  I'm trying to find out if aws sync can handle open files.